# Problem with SUBSTITUTE function in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm having problems using the SUBSTITUTE function as part of a formula.  On it's own, SUBSTITUTE returns the desired output (i.e. in cell O3), but when combined in a formula, 0 is outputted (i.e. cell P3).

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

For informatation, the formula in cell O3 is 
`=IF(ISNUMBER(N3), N3-SUBSTITUTE(M3, "+", ""), "")`

Comment: Thanks @pnuts - I've just tried to recreate the cells from scratch and I'm still having the same problem...  Is yours working with data exactly as in the screenshot?

Comment: Good spot, and it definitely works now.  I think it's more so silly me for not realising that it would round-down...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are getting the correct answer but .2857 is being rounded down to less than £1! (ie it is just the formatting).